# typescript error "Not all code paths return a value." when i try to manipulate response and return, but direct return response works fine

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, async-await, rxjs

i have a situation where i try to manipulate/process response and return but then I get error from typescript **Not all code paths return a value.** Im fetching the data from a backend API using RxJS `lastValueFrom` operator. I also use some lodash functions as helper

for example it gives error when i do this

```js
  async getMoviesByIds(movieIds: string[]) {
    try {
      const uniqueMovieIds = uniq(movieIds);
      const response: any = await lastValueFrom(this.movieService.getMoviesByIds({ movieIds: uniqueMovieIds }));

      if (!response?.movies?.length) return [];

      const moviesWithNames = uniqueMovieIds.map((mId) => response.movies.find((m: any) => m.id === mId)).filter((movie) => movie?.id);
      return moviesWithNames;

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

but it doesnt give error and compiles successfully when i just return response

```js
  async getMoviesByIds(movieIds: string[]) {
    try {
      const uniqueMovieIds = uniq(movieIds);
      const response: any = await lastValueFrom(this.movieService.getMoviesByIds({ movieIds: uniqueMovieIds }));
      return response;
    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
    }
  }
```

why it behaves differently in two situations

Comment: Your `catch()` clause is one path out of the function, and it has no `return` after it captures and logs the error value.

Comment: @Pointy thanks for reply. that makes sense. any idea why the second one compiled without issue?

Comment: Well I noticed that the second sample *should* get the same error (if I'm correct about what I said).  I know that Java would complain about that in a method that should return a value of some type. It *might* be because in the second sample, you're returning `response`, and it has type `any` which includes `undefined`.

Comment: @Pointy interesting. i now checked with `const moviesWithNames: any`  and now it is compiling without errors. wouldnt have noticed it myself

Comment: `const response: any`  <-- is there any reason your killing your types here. ?

Comment: @Keith im using angular and tied to using typescript :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Also return something in `catch` block.

```
async getMoviesByIds(movieIds: string[]) {
    try {
      const uniqueMovieIds = uniq(movieIds);
      const response: any = await lastValueFrom(this.movieService.getMoviesByIds({ movieIds: uniqueMovieIds }));

      if (!response?.movies?.length) return [];

      const moviesWithNames = uniqueMovieIds.map((mId) => response.movies.find((m: any) => m.id === mId)).filter((movie) => movie?.id);
      return moviesWithNames;

    } catch (e) {
      console.error(e);
      return e 
      // OR return []
    }
  }
```

Comment: thanks for answer. any idea why the second one compiled succesfuly?